# Waterfall Dialog Not Running One At A Time

Tags: botframework

I have the following code:

```
this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt("tp"));
this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt("tp2"));
this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt("tp3"));
this.dialogs.add(
    new WaterfallDialog("send_email", [
        this.promptStep.bind(this),
        async step => await step.prompt("tp", "Who do you want to email?"),
        async step => await step.prompt("tp2", "What's the subject line?"),
        async step => await step.prompt("tp3", "And what's the message?"),
        async step => await OAuthHelpers.sendMail(step.context, step.result, step.result)
    ])
);
```

When I run this in the bot emulator, the first two text prompts are shows right away. It doesn't even wait for my response. How can I tell it to wait for the user response before continuing?

[image]

Comment: Can you share what the implementation of your actual bot's onTurn handler looks like?

Comment: @DrewMarsh sure: https://i.imgur.com/o1sXJEG.png

Comment: Ah, ok so you are handling conversationUpdate activities... that's good, but now I need to see your processInput method. If you can throw the whole file up in a gist or something that might be the fastest approach. :)

Comment: sure: https://gist.github.com/AskYous/5f8da20bccc42ad6d33bce49b73d250a

FYI It's written in typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so based on the gist you linked in the comments, I believe your problem is likely due to some of the dialog processing going on inside [the `processStep` function](https://gist.github.com/AskYous/5f8da20bccc42ad6d33bce49b73d250a#file-bot-ts-L78). Specifically I see two problems around how you start up the `"send_email"` waterfall dialog.

Starting on [line 98](https://gist.github.com/AskYous/5f8da20bccc42ad6d33bce49b73d250a#file-bot-ts-L98) you have:

```
const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(step.context);
await dc.beginDialog("send_email");
```

The first thing is you shouldn't be creating a whole new `DialogContext` here with the call to `createContext`. You already have a context within the step, you just want to push another dialog onto the stack with `beginDialog`.

The second thing is that, while you `await` that, you don't `return` and the logic will flow through down to [line 112](https://gist.github.com/AskYous/5f8da20bccc42ad6d33bce49b73d250a#file-bot-ts-L112) which will then call `endDialog` which you don't want to do in this case as it will simply kill the current dialog you just put onto the stack.

Ultimately, those two lines should be changed to simply be:

```
return await step.beginDialog("send_email");
```

This will begin the `"send_email"` dialog flow and allow it to move forward appropriately. Ultimately when that flow finishes it would return to your `"graphDialog"` to execute the next step, but because there are no more steps it will just complete that dialog automatically and return you to an empty stack which your `onTurn` logic already deals with by beginning the `"graphDialog"` again. Now, if you wanted to avoid that, then you'll need to make a few other changes to your flow, but hopefully this gets you going.